# How to replace a text with a certain ID with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace

I am doing some beginner exercises with JavaScript in order to learn but I'm coming up with an issue.

What I am trying to accomplish is replacing text with a certain ID. I have a 3 links all with text "Quote" which with their own ID(q1,q2,q3). However the function that I am calling is replacing the first instance of "Quote" so the issue is obviously my function.

How can I make it so that it only replaces that ID "Quote".

This is my function:

```
function quotation(c){
    if ( c == q1){
    var x = document.getElementByID("q1");
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(x.innerHTML, 'Hello World');
}
```

Comment: That is correct `.replace` only replaces one instance. You need to use a regular expression. For example in your case `new RegExp(x.innerHTML,"g")` the g is for global. Alternatively, use a for loop.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have not learned about RegExp as of yet

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev.shtml

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum also I forgot to mention I did this for q2 and q3. and q3 changes q1. I want it so q3 only changes q3. Sorry for leaving that part out

Comment: in which format your id is existing?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it is as simple as this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpjava/CYGm5/):

```
<a id="q1" href="#">Quote</a>
<a id="q2" href="#">Quote</a>
<a id="q3" href="#">Quote</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function quotation(id, text) {
    var q = document.getElementById(id);
    if (q) q.innerHTML = text;
  }
  quotation('q1', 'Hello World');

</script>
```

Comment: @user3075178 was replacing the inner HTML of the entire BODY with anything that matched 'Quote', because that was x.innerHTML. That's why every element was changing. Simply change x.innerHTML since you already found the correct element!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I framed the HTML as

```
<a id='q1'>Quota</a>
<a id='q2'>Quota</a>
<a id='q3'>Quota</a>
```

As per your code, you're changing the text of the `q1` element.  So it was working as expected.  Due to some edge case I messed my answer.  Now What you need to do is simply add a class to your `a` tags like

```
<a id='q1' class='q'>Quota</a>
<a id='q2' class='q'>Quota</a>
<a id='q3' class='q'>Quota</a>
```

And within your function, iterate each elements; so that you can replace for all the elements.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("q");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(x[i].innerHTML, 'Hello World');
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rfKcM/12/)

Hope you understand.

Comment: No (read the behavior he describes), also,  - there is no third 'g' parameter in .replace

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Actually you can specify flags as the third argument, but it's not standardized or recommended.

Comment: @j08691 only when you pass a regular expression to begin with iirc, and only in some browsers. For example in Chrome and IE11 `"HHHHH".replace("H","A","g")` returns "AHHHH"` but in firefox it works.

Comment: @j08691 that earlier comment is incorrect - it's only if you pass a _string_ (in firefox)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Your right, I checked it.  instead if I try like this `"HHHHH".replace(/H/g,"A")` it gives the correct answer `"AAAAA"`.  here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfKcM/8/) working in chrome and ff

Comment: @Praveen please consider checking how regular expressions literal work, doing `/x.innerHTML/g` is comparable to doing `"x.innerHTML"` it doesn't interpolate.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum while testing I found what I meant is wrong.  I will delete my answer. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: @Praveen or improve it! That's better. The correct solution requires using the regexp constructor (Like in my comment above) and using an `escape` function (see SO questions about escaping regex in JavaScript)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I think in the above case it seems that OP is replacing it for a particular `element` using `id`.  As you mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651678/how-to-replace-a-text-with-a-certain-id-with-javascript#comment32723534_21651678) it is better to go with looping I think so.